# How do I build an executable file in visual studio 2010 that doesn't rely on the .NET 4 SDK DLL/Library files?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, sdk, build

How do I build an executable file in visual studio 2010 that doesn't rely on the .NET 4 SDK DLL/Library files?

I'm getting an error that informs that the system.dll is missing, I'm assuming this is part of the SDK.

Comment: You don't need the SDK, you need the redistributable framework. And no, it's impossible to write .NET applications that don't require the .NET Framework. You'll need to write an unmanaged Win32 application, instead.

Comment: I have installed the re-distributable frameworks but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Well, that's impossible. If you install the correct version of the .NET Framework, your program will run fine without any errors. Update your question with more information, like the *specific* error message that you're getting.

Comment: "SystemDllNotFoundException", I just think my executable is looking for the DLLs at runtime using directories that point to the SDK rather than the framework.

Comment: Hard to say, you haven't shown us any code. That's certainly not a *normal* thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building a .Net application this is simply not possible.  A .Net application requires the .Net runtime to be installed on the machine that it is run on.

If you're trying to build a pure C++ application which has no .Net framework support then make sure the Common Language Runtime support is disabled for the project.

- Right click on the project and select properties
- Navigate to Configuration Properties -> General
- Ensure "Common Language Runtime Support" is sot to "No Common Language Runtime Support"

Comment: I'm using Pure MSIL common language runtime support

Comment: @Hades that's the source of the problem. Either you need to convert to "no common language runtime support" or accept a .Net runtime dependency for your program

Comment: After switching to CLR runtime support I get: "msvcrt.dll"

Comment: @Hades I'm not sure what you mean by "I get: msvcrt.dll".  Is that an error, dialog, setting, etc ...

Comment: Apologies, msvcrt.dll missing

Comment: @Hades, ah. The file `msvcrt.dll` is the C-runtime DLL. You need to manually deploy that with your application

Comment: So I need to add all the files in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A" to the computer I'm installing the software on manually?

Comment: @Hades no that's not necessary. Deploying C++ is a bit complex and can vary a bit depending on your circumstances. I suggest you start by reading the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx

Comment: installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)
worked. Thanks for your help.